# read -p doesn't prompt the string when combined with 2>/dev/null, why is that?

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a script N as below:

```
read -p "Enter a number" x
if [ x -eq 1 ];then
     echo &x
else
     echo "not equal 1" >&2
fi
```

But when I run this script like this

`N 2>/dev/null`

it doesn't prompt the string in the read command. I understand that 2>/dev/null will redirect the stderr, but why the string in the read command doesn't show either?

Comment: Did you mean `echo $x` rather than `echo &x`?

Comment: yes, it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `read -p` writes the prompt to stderr.

For example:

```
$ read -p 'Prompt: ' x >read.out 2>read.err
42
$ echo $x
42
$ cat read.out
$ cat read.err ; echo ''
Prompt:
$
```

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. It didn't occur to me that the prompt string will be outputted as stderr. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

"x" is variable ,you must use "$x" or "${x}"

```
 read -p "Enter a number" x
    if [ $x -eq 1 ];then
         echo $x
    else
         echo "not equal 1" >&2
    fi
```

something like this

Comment: That was probably just a typo in the question.